# What are the pros and cons of implementing facial recognition oppose to traditional password login system?

Tags: security, web-applications, authentication

Lately I have the idea of developing facial recognition login system for web applications eliminating the need of remembering passwords, I mean we need to advance from password to something futuristic, therefore I would like to know what are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 0):

It will be great, however you have to solve some simple issues:

How to authenticate twins? (it is interesting)

Having a picture of Barack Obama will I be able to login into his account? (possibly it is a cons)